# Find which queries in mysql was made before

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to know which queries was mad before in a mySql database. I want to know if there is a way to find some intstructions did like delete or update in a database.

To know the exact query like : DELETE FROM table_name WHERE some_column=some_value;

Answer (score 1):

You should activate general log in MySQL.
It allows writing statements to table or to specified file.

More info - [The General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html)